# How to enable Visa2 key diversification on GP compliant card?

Tags: javacard, globalplatform

I have developed a Java Card applet for a customer, and now he wants me to enable Visa2 Key Diversification algorithm on his cards. I have never been involved in deploying applets to cards, so this is a new concept for me. The tool I occasionally use to download an applet to a card is `gpj`, and here's the command line I use with my customers' cards:

```
java -jar gpj.jar -mode ENC (-delete/-load/-install/-list/etc...)
```

This causes gpj to use Global Platform default keys (`404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F`) to open a secure channel with security domain on the cards (which is `A0 00 00 00 03 00 00 00`).

One of the cards came with an applet already installed on it  as a sample card, and when I tried the above command with `-list` parameter, I got a "Card Cryptogram Invalid" error from `gpj`. After several trial and errors, I was able to authenticate with the security domain using this command:

```
java -jar gpj.jar -mode ENC -visa2 (-delete/-load/-install/-list/etc...)
```

So, it seems like Visa2 key diversification can be turned on and off on my cards. My question is, how can I achieve this?

Comment: @vojta I want to force the security domain of my cards to use Visa2 key diversification

Comment: @vojta So, am I right to assume that `gpj` uses my key and some data from the card to derive a key for the card?

Comment: Probably It is a Gemalto card. Can't you change the VISA2 authentication keys to `4041...4F` instead of forcing Security Domain to use VISA2 diversification? (You can do that using `gp -visa2 -key 47454D5850524553534F53414D504C45 -unlock -mode clr` command- Download [**this**](https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro) tool instead of _GPJ_. _GPJ_ is too old.) I think after changing the authentication keys to `4041....4F`, you don't need to use `-visa2` in your commands anymore. _47454D5850524553534F53414D504C45 is default value of authentication keys for Gemalto cards._

Comment: @Abraham Thanks for the hint. I want to do the opposite. Lock the cards to visa2 diversification. Can GP do this?

Comment: Well, as I said I **think** the only difference between _VISA2_ cards and the other cards is the authentication keys default value. So, maybe trying this command on the other cards, cause them act like _VISA2_ cards. --> `gp -key 404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f -lock 47454D5850524553534F53414D504C45`. Anyway, I'm not sure about that, please notify me if it works. (Replace `404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f` with the card's authentication key and after executing above command, you can install/delete/... applets with `java -jar gpj.jar -mode ENC -visa2 (-delete/-load/-install/-list)`)

Comment: @Abraham `gp -virgin -lock <mykey>` changes cards keys, but doesn't use Visa2 key diversification to calculate card specific keys. Instead, it sets `<mykey>` as card's new key

Comment: @Abraham I finally got it to work after tracing GP source code. `gp -virgin -lock visa2:<MasterKey> -relax`

Comment: Indeed, the keying options need to be better documented and with the addition of HSM backed keys, the interface will change once again.